# algorithm for parsing appointment data from text email

Tags: algorithm, parsing, calendar

I want to write a parser that takes an email or other text that someone in the general public has sent - something like a birthday party invitation or a meeting announcement.  The idea is to pull out the date and caption and other key info and send an appointment to Google calendar.

My best idea so far is to scan for a bunch of regular expressions that would pick out a date from the text and use that as a starting point.  But then I still have to decide what the caption of the appointment is.

Does anyone have a better idea?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Wow, this is vague. Would the "other text" be known to have a date and "caption" and "other key info"? Or are you trying to pull this from arbitrary text?

Comment: It is pretty much arbitrary text.  For example, the mother of a 1st grader sending an invitation to a birthday party.  It may or may not have a full date even, it might just be something like "this Friday".  But in that case we could probably just kick it out and let a human read it.

Comment: What if there are multiple dates and times in the email?

Comment: @j - if it has multiple distinct dates, it would suspect more than one event and create a record for each.  If it has the same date more than once, it would just create one record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [XKCD Regular Expressions](http://xkcd.com/208/) is appropriate reference :).